# Xamarin Android application

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, xamarin

Started today to develop with xamarin in Visual studio it looks nice so far
But my question is

how to switch from button click to another Layout(View)

When i do this on my login page looks as follow:

```
[Activity(Label = "Test", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Test: Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Afvalwijzer);

        EditText Bla1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Bla1);
        Bla1.Hint = "Your text";

        EditText Bla2= FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Bla2);
        Bla2.Hint = "Your text";

        Button Login = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnLogin);
        Login.Click += new EventHandler(Login_Click);

    }

    void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditText Bla1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Bla1);
        EditText Bla2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Bla2 );

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Bla1.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Bla2.Text))
        {
            AfvalwijzerWS WebS = new AfvalwijzerWS();
            var Data = WebS.Authenticate(Bla1.Text, Bla2.Text);
            TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ContentTextView);

            if (Data.Count() > 0)
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Index);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox("No Access !");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox();
        }
    }
```

This Works fine.
But when im on Index(Layout)
i have the same code like this:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Index);
        Button Contact = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnContact);
        Contact.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Contact);
        };

    }
```

and its referenced in the xml of the layout ofc 
but it wont trigger the button event does someone know why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be starting a new activity, rather than setting the content view

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Index);
        Button Contact = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnContact);
        Contact.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(/* whatever activity you want */ )));

            // e.g.
            //StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(SplashActivity)));
        };

    }
```

Comment: Thanks DaveDev will check it tomorrow and if this works i let you know and accept the answer it looks logical thank you very much